# Direct3D 11 issues in Windows 10(D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO is removed)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, direct3d11

As i  catch it structure D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO  is  deprecated in DX 11 for Windows  8.1 and up,  what kind of structure can i use for replacement  for  this  structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO` is part of the D3DX11 utility library from the DirectX SDK.

**D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are all deprecated along with the legacy DirectX SDK.** See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for the full details here.

Depending on what exactly you were wanting to do with `D3DX11` here, there are a number of different options (all of which are open source under the MIT license).

- The [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) library provides the functionality in D3DX for loading bitmaps, resizing and converting them, generating mipmaps, compressing, and then writing them out as .DDS files. This is usually overkill for most applications to do at run-time, and not a particularly good use of end-user's time anyhow, but it's great for writing custom content tool pipelines for texture processing. The DirectXTex package includes a 'sample' which is the venerable `texconv` command-line tool written to use DirectXTex instead of D3DX.
- The [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) module is intended to handle efficient loading of .DDS files and creating Direct3D 11 resources from them. It does not perform any runtime conversions, so some legacy files with pixel formats that do not directly map to a DXGI format will fail to load and in some cases the DXGI format of the file is not supported by the device and will also fail to load. For these cases, you will want to use DirectXTex to convert them offline to something that you can rely on being able to load on your target machine. This code supports the full range of Direct3D 11 resources including 1D, 2D, 3D, cubemaps, and texture arrays with mipmaps. The DDSTextureLoader module is included in both the [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) library and in the DirectXTex package.
- For very simple cases, there is also a [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) module which can load standard bitmap files, does some runtime conversions and resizing, and then creates a Direct3D 11 texture 2D from it. It can optionally enable the 'auto-gen mipmaps' feature of Direct3D 11 to provide some basic mipmap support as well (standard bitmap files can't store mipmaps with the base image the way a .DDS file can). This makes use of the Windows Imaging Component (WIC), but is much more 'heavyweight' than DDSTextureLoader. This gives you less control over the quality of the filtering (particularly mipmaps), and does not support complex textures like volume maps, cubemaps, or texture arrays. The WICTextureLoader module is also included in both the [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) library and in the DirectXTex package.
- The [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab) module is intended as a light-weight texture saver for creating 'screen shot' bitmap files from render target textures. The ScreenGrab module is included in the [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) library and DirectXTex package.

-- excerpt from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression.aspx)

> For a complete catalog of replacements for legacy D3DX, see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx). There are similar posts for [samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx), [tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx), and the [DirectX components](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx).

Since you've marked this question with the VS 2013 tag, I'm assuming you are using Visual Studio 2013. You should read about the [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/18/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-8-1-sdk-rtm-are-now-available.aspx) that comes with it. There's a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxtk_desktop_2013) for *DirectX Tool Kit* that works with VS 2013 Update 5, as well as a "Direct3D Game" template package for [VS 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux.aspx) that you might want to check out.

Comment: Chuck  I have  installed  DirectX SDK(June 2010)  , i have  done  solid  amount  of correction  in DXUT libraries  and  make it work for  me. On Windows 10 with VS 2015.  Sorry  i couldn't   deal with  new  version of  DXUT11 for Windows 8.1 and  10.   In parallel  i am getting familiar  with  DX 12 , when i  will  try  to  re write  my older  DX 10, DX 11 implementations on DX 12,  will  be  interesting  how  should i deal  with  Windows  API  without DXUT  , hope  DXUT  for  DX 12 will  be  out  as soon as  possible.

Comment: The purpose of [DXUT11 on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT) is to support older codebases and samples so they move away from requiring the legacy DirectX SDK. New projects should probably just avoid it completely and use something else. Perhaps the VS templates I have on another [repo](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) in combination with [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

Comment: If you are targeting Windows 10 only and using VS 2015 already, you can use the Universal Windows Platform which handles packaging, deployment, install, etc. DXUT does not support UWP, but those templates, DirectX Tool Kit, DirectXTex, etc. do.